# Stepwise regression in Python for BNEG models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to select the best features for this regression model.

Here's how the data frame looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ga:productAddsToCart': [2, 2, 4, 2],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_(not set)': [True, False, False, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_2109119DG': [False, True, False, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_2201117SG': [False, False, True, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_2201117TG': [False, False, False, True],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_2201117TL': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_2811': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_5.4': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_5085J': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:mobileDeviceModel_A11': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_l.instagram.com': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_l.wl.co': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_linkedin.com': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_linktr.ee': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_m.facebook.com': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_mercadopago.com.br': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_naturus.com.br': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_ofertadia.com.br': [False, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_pinterest.com': [True, False, False, False],
    'ga:source_youtube.com': [False, False, False, False],
})
```

The data frame contains about 917 one-hot encoded features (columns) and I need to select only the features that have statistical significance.

Here's the code I've tried:

1# Separating the X and y:

```
X = df.drop("ga:productAddsToCart", axis=1)
X = X.astype(int)
y = df["ga:productAddsToCart"]
```

2# running the model

```
model = sm.NegativeBinomial(df['ga:productAddsToCart'], df.drop('ga:productAddsToCart', axis=1))
```

3# Feature selecting

```
seletor_forward = SequentialFeatureSelector(clone(model), forward=True, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

seletor_forward.fit(X, y)


plot_sequential_feature_selection(seletor_forward.get_metric_dict())
```

**This code returns the error:
TypeError: Cannot clone object '' (type ): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.**